# Google Spreadsheet onEdit not being triggered by row movement

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to call `onEdit()` to renumber rows automatically when they are moved. As far as I can tell, it is only invoked if there is a change in cell text rather than position. Is there an alternative method, or a way to monitor the spreadsheet's activity to include row repositioning?